How to join a string onto the output from an array
Let's say this is my output from an aws-cli command.
{
    "imageIds": [
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:9"
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:5"
        },
        {
            "imageDigest": "sha256:46",
            "imageTag": "latest"
        }
    ]
}

Using:
--query="imageIds[?imageTag != 'latest'].imageDigest"

Gives me ["sha256:9", "sha256:5", "sha256:46"].
How do I join an additional string to that list, either using the query, jq or bash, so it looks like
["X sha256:9", "X sha256:5", "X sha256:46"]?

There's an extra , before ].

Single quotes are not permitted in JSON as string delimiters.

$ echo '["sha256:9", "sha256:5", "sha256:46"]' | jq 'map("X " + .)'
[
  "X sha256:9",
  "X sha256:5",
  "X sha256:46"
]

Note that strings are delimited with double quotes, not single quotes.

Just incase this was what you wanted to do ....
jq -r '.imageIds
# removes latest
| map(select(.imageTag != "latest")
# format command to run in bash
| "aws ecr start-image-scan --repository-name sample-repo --image-id imageDigest=\(.imageDigest)")[]

Output
aws ecr start-image-scan --repository-name sample-repo --image-id imageDigest=sha256:9
aws ecr start-image-scan --repository-name sample-repo --image-id imageDigest=sha256:5


Thanks. Not sure why I'd want to do that. It states its a vulnerability scan yet doesn't indicate anything about security vulnerability. Either way its too late since it already got pushed to aws?

the aws part was just an example to show what a command would look like in place of X - i probably should have gone with this instead:
| "echo \(.imageDigest)")[]
